# How does device registration work between Azure and FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have set up an Azure notification hub that is linked to FCM to send push notifications to Android devices and all appears to be working fine.

I don't understand how the two systems relate to each other although - when a device registers (for the first time) it is with Azure, but then how does FCM know about the device (since it is FCM that ultimately communicates with the device). 
Is a device ID created on each system ie. Azure and FCM both maintain a list of registered devices?

[UPDATE]

Looking more carefully at the registration code, I have found that the device FIRST registers with FCM (I incorrectly assumed Azure was the entry point). 
So FCM provides a token once the device is registered, that token is then registered in Azure. So the references are Azure->FCM and FCM->Device

Comment: If you want to know how push notications work, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview#how-push-notifications-work).

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that article and I understand the difference between Azure/FCM but its specifically the registration bit that interests me. I've since found out some more info regarding this and I've updated my question.